# How do I require users to license future submissions on sign-up?

Tags: licensing, contributor-agreements, contracts, terms-of-service

Users will submit content to my website. I want them to license that content under [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) when they do, otherwise they should not submit it. Thus, all user-submitted content will be released under this license.

I'm guessing this means they need to read and agree to a Terms Of Service. Is there a standard or common way to present a ToS (or other mechanism) that is *specifically appealing* to the libre/sharing/commons community?

(This question isn't limited to CC BY 4.0, imagine it's any Free Cultural Work license.)

Comment: example suggested by CC http://contributoragreements.org

Answer (score 2):

The way that [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) does it is a simple statement that you have read and agree with the Terms of Service when registering for an account.
Some sites use a slightly stronger indication by requiring you to check a check-box to indicate you agree with the ToS.
This is all very standard for sites that allow the creation of accounts.

In the Terms of Service you need to make it clear that user-provided content is licensed to you under the CC-BY license. You could look at the [ToS for StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/legal) for inspiration.

Comment: is there a way to present this that is specifically appealing to the libre/sharing/commons community (I've updated my question to add this emphasis)

Comment: for example, I just found out that Wikidata calls it "terms of use" - is this a thing?